# Analytical solution for non-linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following differential equation
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{-a x^2}{1 + bx}$$

where $a,b$ are constants.

How is this solved analytically? I want to find some explicit function $x(t)$.

Comment: x= x0 at t= t0; x= x at t= t;

Comment: @user154664 are these initial conditions?

Comment: @Amzoti I want x as an explicit function of t.

Comment: @DanZimm They are the limits of integration.

Comment: I imagine you have separated the variables and integrated. We get something like $-\frac{1}{x}+b\ln(|x|)=-at+C$. This cannot be solved for $x$ in terms of elementary functions. Possibly something can be done with the Lambert $W$-function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said by David, the solution of the differential equation is $$\frac{b \log (x)}{a}-\frac{1}{a x}=t+c$$ The explicit solution for $x$ can only be obtained using the Lambert function and, in this particular case, $$x=\frac{1}{b W\left(\frac{e^{-\frac{a (c+t)}{b}}}{b}\right)}$$ which cannot be expressed in terms of any elementary functions.

Comment: You are very welcome. Remember Lambert function : it is more and more used and provides very nice closed forms in many domains. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a separable DE: you can get all the $x$s on one side and all the $t$s on the other and then integrate:
$$\int\frac{1+bx}{ax^2}\,dx=\int dt\ .$$
See if you can do the next couple of steps to obtain an equation giving $x$ implicitly in terms of $t$.

The implicit equation will have a $1/x$ term and a logarithmic term, and MAPLE gives a solution in terms of the [Lambert $W$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).  It is very unlikely that there will be an elementary solution for $x(t)$.